# T-SQL XQuery Node Value Path not Matching

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql

While this works for retrieving `local-name(.)` node names as demonstrated [here](http://marcanton.io/blog/the-cheaters-guide-to-mastering-xquery-on-sql-server-part-1/) I can't get a table with resume first name and resume last name for each job candidate.

```
    USE AdventureWorks2012;

    WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
     'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume'
      AS ns)

      SELECT 
        T.rows.value('(ns:Name.First)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS firstName, 
        T.rows.value('(ns:Name.Last)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS lastName
      FROM HumanResources.JobCandidate
      CROSS APPLY
        Resume.nodes('//ns:Name/*') AS T(rows);
```

The error message lists the nodes that are in context, including what appears to be the targeted node.

> XQuery [HumanResources.JobCandidate.Resume.value()]: There is no element named 
>      "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume}:*Name.First*" 
>      in the type 
>     "element(ns{http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume}:Name.Prefix,xs:string) | 
>      element(ns{http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume}:*Name.First*,xs:string)

...

> element(ns{http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume}:Name.Last,xs:string) | 
>      element(ns{http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume}:Name.Suffix,xs:string)".

Is the problem that the `element` is a level down?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that context was a level too deep.  Fixed by removing `/*` from `nodes` path.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume'
  AS ns)

  SELECT 
    T.rows.value('(ns:Name.First)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS firstName, 
    T.rows.value('(ns:Name.Last)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS lastName
  FROM HumanResources.JobCandidate
  CROSS APPLY
    Resume.nodes('//ns:Name/*') AS T(rows);
```